# Imageview shows border around photo that does not exist in the source image

Tags: android, imageview

I'm trying to display a simple image in an `imageview` and it seems to be adding a border around the photo that isn't there in the source image. I placed the `imageview` in the parent view and set the image to it, and in the editor you can see a small sliver of the border but when I run it on a device or emulator more of a border appears.

I tried removing a pixel off the size of the photo in case there was a border but that didn't fix it. Below are the photos of the emulator and the editor to show the difference.

Editor:
[image]

Emulator:
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

EDIT: added xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_home_screen"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="frolicindustries.strandstudybible.HomeScreen"
android:weightSum="1"
android:background="@android:color/background_light"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:baselineAligned="false">
<!--android:scaleType="fitCenter"-->
<!--android:cropToPadding="false"-->
<!--android:layout_weight="0.01"-->

<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/About"
    android:background="@drawable/aboutgradient"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_height="65sp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Extras"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/Extras"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Bible"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Bible" />

<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Extras"
    android:background="@drawable/extragradient"
    android:layout_height="65sp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/About"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/WTFW"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/WTFW"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Bible"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Bible" />

<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Bible"
    android:background="@drawable/biblegradient"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:layout_height="65sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-5dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="-5dip"
    android:layout_above="@+id/WTFW" />

<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/WTFW"
    android:background="@drawable/wtfwgradient"
    android:layout_height="65sp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/Extras"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Bible"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/Bible"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Bible"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Bible" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    android:background="@null"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Bible"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/Bible"
    android:layout_height="155sp" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/title"
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_weight="0.29"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/Bible"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView2"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: is this a 9-patch-image?

Comment: I believe so, I had a tool generate  the different scales of images from my source one

Comment: Please post your xml file.

Comment: @staticFlow maybe you have used `wrap_content` ? try to add a background color also in your image view with src and see if the border color changes.If yes your image is small and you wrapped it! if not you have a problem with your image re design it.

Comment: @Charuka I added a background and it did show behind it but the image is not set to wrap_content

Comment: @staticFlow have a look on what i said hope it will be helpful for you to find out what went wrong!! I mentioned a same scenario as yours  well

Comment: @staticFlow what it means is it's not your padding your image is not just perfectly fits try some scale type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this,

my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#000"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.charu.its2017huree.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:orientation="vertical">


 <ImageView
     android:background="#FFF"
     android:src="@drawable/amanda"
     android:id="@+id/my_image_view"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="300dp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

I have set an `imageView` and i found out it seems there is something wrong with it's left and right edges. I have given `match_parent` to my imageView already.So I add a background color to my `imageView` to find out what's going on.

But that's not enough for me i want to see the boundaries as well.It's there on your android mobile!

*Settings >Developer Options >(scroll bit down) under category Drawing there is a option **Show layout boundaries** > Tick that option* .. mm You get some kind of grids in your mobile.It's normal it will be gone when you untick that option.

[image]

Let's jump back to image view  and see how it looks now!

1. Now i can clearly see a background color which i add in behind of the image
2. Also image view width boundary is fine,it's `match_parent`.You can see that from your *layout boundaries*.

[image]

MM sounds like image didn't fit properly then i try something with `scaleType`  like `android:scaleType="fitXY"` and run and see how is it now .. all-right it seems she has taken the full space .. I mean in my `imageView` :D

This way you can clearly identify what'w wrong with your `imageView`

[image]

Comment: Hey.. you..yes you .. don't look at her!!! If its helpful hit and upvote :D

Comment: what IDE are you using? I can't seem to fin  that option in the android studio.

Comment: @staticFlow its not from android studio its from OS android.It's there on your phone

Comment: @staticFlow did that helped to solve your issue ? or you still have it

Comment: yes it did thank you! changing it to fitXY is what did it

Comment: @staticFlow Happy to help :))

Answer (score 0):

what is your image saved as? i would suggest .png extension. I would get the border when my images are jpg or anything else.

Comment: The image is a high res vector graphic file in png format, but thank you for the suggestion :)